# Decimal Places - how to implement feature from "blender.developer.org"?

Tags: add-on, customization, experimental-features

## How to implement to my blender Decimal Places?

**I found this** (https://developer.blender.org/D14095) **very usefull for my furniture project.**

- Some advice? thank you in advance!

[image]

(Picture download from that post)

Comment: You'd need to be able to recompile Blender and add the changes in the code shown some way down that page and there are quite a few of them!

Comment: yes. although they suggested it could be part of the "developer extras" they did not implement this and they are not sure if it is even a good idea since it's a rare scenario when this will be used. so don't keep your hopes up on this one.

Comment: I wish they could turn into some addon or something like that..... that precision could help in designing the product.

Comment: @JohnEason How to do that?

Comment: @AtelierMorphArt-Voleybot go to the command line or your terminal and checkout the repository with `git clone git://git.blender.org/blender.git` then follow steps here https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Tools/Git then make your code changes and compile the code https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender

Comment: To be honest, if you aren't familiar with compiling code and don't have the required C compiler I wouldn't even think about it!

Comment: `make && make my-code && make fix-bugs && make nice` 